# java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format how can i fix the problem?

Tags: android, flutter, keystore, sha1

I've been trying to solve the problem for the past 5 hours, but I just can't find the problem. I just want to have the SHA-1 value and then enter this command in my project in the terminal, but an error message comes up all the time and I can't find a solution.

`keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\kokot\.android\debug.keystore`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGwV7.png)

the path to debug.keystore is also right
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMocw.png)

Even if I create the keystore file again, errors come up. But to be honest, I don't even really understand the problem, because it's the first time I've had one and I can't find much about it on the internet.

``

Comment: try adding -storetype JKS or -storetype PKCS12

Comment: Why don't you use Android studio to do it?

Comment: No if i use -storetype PKCS12 at the end he says 'data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys i made it I got my SHA-1 value!!! It just took me 15 hours hahaha

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#create-an-upload-keystore

if you have executed the code as in the link, then enter `keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\$Username\upload-keystore.jks`

Then the program will give you your SHA-1 value without any problems.